# Spark SQL (Databricks) - AnalysisException: cannot evaluate expression outer() in inline table definition - Multicolumn aggregate

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

I am migrating to (Azure) Databricks 6.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11) from some real relational Databases. I only use Spark SQL for it.

Because MIN is an aggregate function, and getting the MIN of multiple values (columns not rows) is cumbersome I used the VALUES Row Constructor to create inline Sub-queries and used the MIN aggregate function over this sub-query to produce simple statements.

the VALUE ROW constructor works fine

```sql
select min(MinLatency) from (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8)) MINL(MinLatency)
```

like for this query (Side question, why cannot I write min(MINL.MinLatency) - but this is not an issue)

Also as subquery it works

```sql
select 
  Latency,
  (select sum(C1) from (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8)) Y(C1)) as C 
from 
  (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8)) as X(Latency)
```

But doing a real Query like (simplified with constants only for this example)

```sql
select 
  T1.ID,
  --min of 4 Values
  T1.C1, T2.C2, T3.C3, T4.C4,
  --(select min(Value) from (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) TI(Value)) as MIN
  (select min(Value) from (VALUES(T1.C1),(T2.C2),(T3.C3),(T4.C4)) TI(Value)) as MIN
from 
  (select 1 as ID, 1 as C1 union all select 2 as ID, 1 as C1) T1
  inner join (select 1 as ID, 2 as C2 union all select 2 as ID, 2 as C2) T2 on T1.ID=T2.ID
  inner join (select 1 as ID, 3 as C3 union all select 2 as ID, 3 as C3) T3 on T1.ID=T3.ID
  inner join (select 1 as ID, 4 as C4 union all select 2 as ID, 4 as C4) T4 on T1.ID=T4.ID
```

Databricks / Spark returns the Error

**Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot evaluate expression outer() in inline table definition; line 6 pos 34**

If you try it with the constants it works.

The Questions are really,

- what do I do wrong?
- is it really not supported? why?
- how do I do multi column MIN as simple as this in Spark SQL? (like min does ignoring NULL values)

Help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: check https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#least

Comment: I did not see that. Is there then also a function for "most / aka MAX" and "STDDEV" where I can use that?

Comment: use greatest for max: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest. you might have to write a udf for stddev in row-wise.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values are never `NULL`, the simplest solution is `LEAST()`:

```
select T1.ID,
       --min of 4 Values
       T1.C1, T2.C2, T3.C3, T4.C4,
       least(T1.C1, T2.C2, T3.C3, T4.C4)
. . .
```

You can also do this using a lateral view.  A simplified example would be:

```
select t1.id, min(c)
from t1 lateral view
     explode(array(c1, c2, c3, c4)) c
group by t1.id;
```

Comment: I did not see find LEAST. As asked above, is there one also for MAX and STDDEV?

Comment: I did not see/find LEAST. As asked above, is there one function also for MAX and STDDEV? Would the EXPLODE type of solution also work if I have to do it 15 times ( 5 Columns Min / 5 Columns Max / 5 Columsn with STDDEV)? MIN/MAX should work because the cartesian product does not matter for MIN/MAX - but STDDEV would be wrong over this, wouldn´t it? I would have to do a subquery for each and join the results to get this done, wouldn´t I.

Comment: @hmayer1980 . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a question about a different calculation on 15 columns, please ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: For MAX, use `GREATEST` instead of `LEAST`.